# segmentation fault while freeing pointer

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++17, double-free

```
class matrix
{
public:
    int nrow;
    int ncol;
    double **m;

    matrix(int r, int c)
    {
        nrow = r; ncol = c;

        m = (double**)malloc(nrow*sizeof(double*));
        for(int i=0; i<nrow; i++)
            m[i] = (double*)malloc(ncol*sizeof(double));

        for(int i=0; i<nrow; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<ncol; j++)
                m[i][j] = 0;
    }

    ~matrix()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<nrow; i++)
        {
            printf("destructor loop: %d\n", i); fflush(stdout);
            free(m[i]);
        }
        free(m);
    }

    matrix(const matrix& that)
    {
        this->nrow = that.nrow;
        this->ncol = that.ncol;

        this->m = (double**)malloc(nrow*sizeof(double*));   // dynamic mem allocation
        for(int i=0; i<this->nrow; i++)
            m[i] = (double*)malloc(ncol*sizeof(double));

        for(int i=0; i<that.nrow; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<that.ncol; j++)
                this->m[i][j] = that.m[i][j]; 
    }

    void operator=(const matrix &that)
    {
        this->nrow = that.nrow;
        this->ncol = that.ncol;

        for(int i=0; i<nrow; i++)  // clear current m
            free(m[i]);
        free(m);

        this->m = (double**)malloc(nrow*sizeof(double*));   // dynamic mem allocation
        for(int i=0; i<this->nrow; i++)
            m[i] = (double*)malloc(ncol*sizeof(double));

        for(int i=0; i<that.nrow; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<that.ncol; j++)
                this->m[i][j] = that.m[i][j]; 
    }

    void show()
    {
        printf("  Marix:\n");
        for(int i=0; i<nrow; i++)
        {
            printf("  ");
            for(int j=0; j<ncol; j++)
            {
                if(m[i][j] >= 0) printf(" ");
                printf("%.6lf ", m[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    matrix cofactor(int r, int c) // returns cofactor of a[r][c]
    {
        printf("cofactor: size:(%d, %d) element:(%d, %d)\n", nrow, ncol, r, c); fflush(stdout);

        matrix ans(nrow-1, ncol-1);

        int x = 0, y = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<nrow; i++)
        {
            if(i == r) continue;
            for(int j=0; j<ncol; j++)
            {
                if(j == c) continue;
                ans.m[x][y] = m[i][j];
                y++;
            }
            x++;
        }
        return ans;
    }

    double det()
    {
        if(nrow != ncol)
        {
            printf("non-square matrix: (%d, %d)\n\n", nrow, ncol);
            exit(1);
        }

        if(nrow == 1) return m[0][0]; 
        if(nrow == 2) 
        {
            double ans = m[0][0]*m[1][1] - m[1][0]*m[0][1];
            return ans;
        }

        double ans = 0;
        int sign = 1;
        for(int i=0; i<nrow; i++)
        {
            printf("det[size:%d, %d] loop row: %d\n", nrow, ncol, i); fflush(stdout);
            matrix a(2, 2); 
            a = cofactor(i, 0);
            ans += (sign*a.det());
            sign = sign*(-1);
        }
        return ans;
    }
};

int main()
{
    matrix c(3, 3);
    c.m[0][0] = 2; c.m[0][1] = -3; c.m[0][2] =  1;
    c.m[1][0] = 2; c.m[1][1] =  0; c.m[1][2] = -3;
    c.m[2][0] = 1; c.m[2][1] =  4; c.m[2][2] =  5;

    c.show();
    printf("determinant: %lf\n", c.det());

    return 0;
}
```

A segmentation fault occurs when calling the det function for even 3x3 matrices.
i do not have experience with sophisticated debuggers but using printf statements it looks like the runtime error occurs during an iteration of the loop in the destructor. also i have tried using vector< vector< double >> instead of double**. i assumed it would not need a destructor in that case. then it is giving me a "double free error". i understand when it occurs but cannot find the error in my code. i have also tried calculating the cofactor inline instead of calling a function but it does not help.

Comment: I suspect the `void operator=(const matrix &that)` overload is freeing what is also freed by the destructor.

Comment: Compile the program with `-fsanitize=address` to get a lot more information when you have memory errors.

Comment: In your assignment-operator, you set `this->nrow = that.nrow` *before* you free your old arrays.  That means that you are calling `free()` on the wrong number of rows in any case where `that.nrow != this.nrow`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yea sorry i fixed that. it did not solve the error unfortunately.

Comment: Also, for `row 1` you are constructing 2 confactor (2x2) matricies before the destructor is called on the first, where with `row 0` you construct and destruct a single (2x2). The segfault seems to occur on `row 1` as soon as `destructor loop: 0` is called after the destructor is called on the first (2x2) cofactor matrix. No I don't have an answer for why yet.

Comment: @narutouzumaki798 try putting a `printf("@%i I just allocated %p\n", __LINE__, theReturnValueFromMalloc);` right after each of your `malloc()` calls, and also a `printf("@%i I'm about to free(%p)\n", __LINE__, theValueYouAreAboutToPassToFree);` call right before each of your `free()` calls.  Then run your program with its stdout redirected to a file, and go into that file, and for each "I'm just malloced(X)" line, find the next matching "I'm about to free(X)" line and delete them both.  Once you've done as many as you can do, whatever "I'm about to free" lines still left are your errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<nrow; i++)
    {
        if(i == r) continue;
        for(int j=0; j<ncol; j++)
        {
            if(j == c) continue;
            ans.m[x][y] = m[i][j];
            y++;
        }
        x++;
    }
```

The logic for incrementing `y` is broken here. Perform a simple mental experiment. If the original matrixes are 3x3, and they are being reduced here to a `2x2` matrix, your `ans`, then you expect each value in `ans` to be initialized here, and

```
            ans.m[x][y] = m[i][j];
            y++;
```

will get executed four times. Since `y` is initially set to 0 ***and never gets reset to 0***, the value of `y` used in this assignment will range from 0 to 3, so, at some point, this will attempt to assign something to `ans.m[x][3]`, which, of course, doesn't exist, and hillarity ensues.

It seems that the obvious intent here is to reset

```
  y=0;
```

As the very first order of business in the outer `for` loop, instead of just once, at the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the cofactor function. You have declared `int x = 0, y = 0` outside of the loops. In the case of x (the row of the cofactor matrix, ans) its fine. But we want the y to be 0 everytime we start with a new row, i.e. y should be in sync with j, skipping when `j==c`.

What is happening is you skip row 0, since `i==r`, then in the next row (`i=1`), you iterate over the columns, skip col 0, since `j==c`, then go over col 1, col 2, so the code that got executed was
`ans.m[0][0] = m[1][1]`, `y++`,
`ans.m[0][1] = m.[1][2]`, `y++`, then we are done with the columns.

We increment x (`x=1` now), we go to the next row, row 2 (`i=2`), but `y=2`, and not reset. So the next row executes this code:
`ans.m[1][2] = m[2][1]` (skipping col 0),
which is out of bounds for `ans`, since `ans` has `ncols-1 = 2` columns.

This results in an error when the destructor for `ans` is called at the end of cofactor function. I fixed the cofactor code, and this results in no errors when calling det for 3*3 matrices.

```
matrix cofactor(int r, int c) // returns cofactor of a[r][c]
{
    printf("cofactor: size:(%d, %d) element:(%d, %d)\n", nrow, ncol, r, c); fflush(stdout);

    matrix ans(nrow-1, ncol-1);

    int x = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<nrow; i++)
    {
        if(i == r) continue;
        int y = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<ncol; j++)
        {
            if(j == c) continue;
            ans.m[x][y] = m[i][j];
            y++;
        }
        x++;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

To debug, I would recommend gdb. You can use onlinegdb.com paste your code there, click debug. Then set breakpoints by break <line_number>, then run, n for next instruction, s for step into function. You can search to find out more.

Comment: You both got my upvote. Can you make your second paragraph into bullets or something to make it easier to read though?